# Recursive fibonacci in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, recursion

My fibonacci function seems to hang infinitely if I give it anything higher than 1?

```
function fibonacci($n) {
    if ($n -lt 2) {
        return 1
    } else {
        return (fibonacci $n - 1) + (fibonacci $n - 2)
    }
}
```

I may be fundamentally misunderstanding how recursion happens in PowerShell... but I can't see how.

Comment: I think you want `if ($n -lt 2) { return $n }`

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis around the arguments for the function calls ... `return (fibonacci ($n - 1)) + (fibonacci ($n - 2))`  should do the trick

Comment: ... and shouldn't it be `if ($n -le 2) { return 1 }`??

Comment: `if ($n -le 2) { return  [math]::Sign( [math]::Max( 0, $n)) }` ( plus @Olaf's fundamental improvement with parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

Some minor adjustments needed. As mentioned by a few people, you missed a couple vital parentheses and you should return `$n` in the if-statement.

The return keyword is not necessary at all in PowerShell btw so I omitted that.

This works:

```
function fibonacci($n) {
      if ($n -lt 2) {
        $n
      }
      else {
        (fibonacci ($n - 1)) + (fibonacci ($n - 2))
      }
}
```

Edit: You should also get in the habit of using the `Verb-Noun` format in PowerShell, something like `Get-Fibonacci` instead of just `fibonacci`.

Comment: Even if the code works the result is wrong. As I mentioned it in my comment above - the return value for 1 AND 2 should be 1!!  ;-)

Comment: You sure? If I run `(0..10).ForEach({fibonacci $_})` I get the correct Fibonacci sequence...

Comment: Actually I am. The fibonacci number for 2 is 1.

Comment: @Olaf Not that part, you are quite correct, I meant are you sure the code doesn't work? Because that's exactly what it returns, it correctly returns the fibonacci sequence, ie. for my example above I get 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 etc. just as expected. That is, `fibonacci 1` and `fibonacci 2` both correctly return `1`.

Comment: hmmmm ... I just figured out it actually does not make any difference ... both ways return the correct vaules.  ...  funny ... ;-)  ... so I appologize for my comment above. I was wrong

Comment: Easy mistake, I totally see how it looks wrong, but it does work.